# In socket prgramming in "C" how do I find out the IP address of the Client who is connecting to the Server?

Tags: c, sockets

In socket prgramming in "C" how do I find out the IP address of the Client who is connecting to the Server? How can the server get the client's IP address?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't mention any API, but the [`accept`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/accept.html) function/system call generally accepts a `sockaddr *` argument where it stores the address of the peer.

```
int accept(int socket, struct sockaddr *restrict address, /* <---- */
       socklen_t *restrict address_len);
```

Alternatively you can use [`getpeername`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpeername.html) to retrieve the same address at a later time.

```
int getpeername(int socket, struct sockaddr *restrict address,
       socklen_t *restrict address_len);
```

If you happen to use winapi: [`accept`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737526), [`getpeername`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738533).